# icCube - XMLA authentication/authorization not working as expected

Tags: xmla, iccube, iccube-reporting

I am trying to limit user to see only one schema over XMLA.

For that i have done:

created separate role without full access check

1. Created separate role without full access check
2. In Applications tab checked only XMLA
3. In Schemas tab selected "Authorize Selected" and select only one schema
4. Created user with just created role
5. applied new user definitions

After that steps, when i connect via XMLA with just created users i still see all schemas.

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

One point that is important when using XMLA interface is to disable the 'anonymous' login. When doing XMLA if this mode is activate it is going to be used in priority.

To change this you need to modify icCube.xml and restart icCube Server. See more on online doc [here](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/configuring_iccube/authentication.php).